# Count values that exist in another table and pivot the result

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot

I want to **count** values from `Chat` table :

```
ID    REASON_ID    DEPARTMENT_ID    
 1      46           1
 2      46           1
 3      50           1
 4      50           2
 5      100          1 
 6      100          2
```

Those exist in `Reason` table :

```
ID    REASON_NAME
46    Reason1
50    Reason2
100   Reason3
```

Where `DEPARTMENT_ID=1`, and I want result like this :

```
ID46  ID50  ID100
 2      1     1
```

How can I do it?

Comment: @mihai I think its different ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic SQL solution is way better, but if you want another option:

```
SELECT SUM(I46) ID46,
SUM(I50) ID50,
SUM(I100) ID100
FROM
(SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN reason_id = 46 THEN 1 END) I46,
COUNT(CASE WHEN reason_id = 50 THEN 1 END) I50,
COUNT(CASE WHEN reason_id = 100 THEN 1 END) I100
FROM chat
WHERE department_id = 1
GROUP BY reason_id) q1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
set @sql = null;
select group_concat( distinct
  concat( ' sum(r.id= ', r.id,') as ID', r.id )
) into @sql
from Chat c
join Reason r on c.reason_id = r.id 
where c.department_id = 1;

set @sql = concat('select ',@sql, ' 
from Chat c
join Reason r on c.reason_id = r.id 
where c.department_id = 1');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76677/31)